# find the values of $a$ for which function is invertible

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I had a question in which i was told to find the range of values of $a$ for which the function is invertible (*for which inverse exist*) and function is $f(x)=ax+3\sin x+4\cos x$

**what i tried**

for inverse to exist function should be monotonic, so $f'(x)$ should be either $>0$ or $<0$
so i took two cases

$$a>3\cos x-4\sin x$$ so i got the minimum and maximum value of the right side of inequality as $5,-5$ but i don't know which inequality i should write, i mean is $a>5$ correct or $a>-5$

and similarly when we discuss other case we get$$a<3\cos x-4\sin x$$
so is $a<5$ correct or $a<-5$?

Comment: Take the intersection it would be $(-\infty,-5)U (5,\infty)$

Comment: Well, in fact for the function to be invertible it should injective (bijective on the codomain if we're given one). Monotonicity guarantees this, and if $\;f\;$ is differentiable then $\;f'\;$ having one unique sign all along the domain guarantees the last one. Yet these are *not* necessary conditions.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar intersection of what?

Comment: @ramsay. I think your signs are wrong for the derivative, not that it makes any practical difference to the answer.

Comment: @almagest thanks

Answer (score 2):

Actually $a \in (-\infty ,-5] \bigcup [5, + \infty)$ is the correct answer. This is because $a$ cannot be inside the image of $g(x)=3\cos x-4\sin x$.

Comment: i didn't get that $a$ needs to be outside image of $g(x)$

Comment: @almagest I made the corrections.

Comment: @EugenCovaci I noticed and upvoted! Incidentally, the derivative is $-\sin x$, not that it makes any difference to the answer.

Comment: but in my book 5, -5 are excluded

Comment: @almagest You're right again. Now I'm beginning to ask myself about the bounds -5, +5 of the $g$ function.Are they  correct?

Comment: I think so, simply because $f(x) I plotted the critical cases 5, -5, but no harm in checking!

Comment: Also $3\sin x+4\cos x=5\sin(x+k)$ for some constant $k$, so the derivative for $a=5$ is just $5(1+\cos(x+k))$ which is never negative and only zero at isolated points. So $f(x)$ is strictly increasing.